# R loop multiple variables within group_by

Tags: r, loops, group-by, summarize

I have an NBA data set with a variable for each player on the court at a given time, and time elapsed during that play.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olWss.png)

I'd like to get the sum of total time played for each player. Creating a single column of player name and total time.

Is there a way to use Summarize and Group_by to loop over each player variable a1,a2, .., h1, h2, .. storing the results. Then combine / append the resulting columns to collapse once more?

The actual data is very large, and the same player can appear multiple times in different a1, a2, etc. columns. Such that after grouping_by each of these independently, it is necessary to consolidate to a single player variable and collapse again.

```
# loop this through a1:5, b1:5 then append and collapse again
nba_sum <- nba_all %>% group_by(a1) %>%
    summarize(sum_time = sum(time,na.rm=TRUE))
```